# Create multiple dynamic CardView in Constraint Layout programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, cardview

I wish to get data from database and replicate this format of CardView with different information but I' facing issue regarding the constraints of the constraint layout. I want to set top of next CardView to the bottom of previous one but ids of both would be generated in real time.

At this time I have this code for sample CardView but it appears at (0,0) position right now. Does anyone have an opinion or an alternative solution to do the same.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_appointment);

        //activity constraint layout
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parentlayout);

        //Adding 2 CardViews
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            CardView cardview = new CardView(this);

            layoutparams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            layoutparams.bottomMargin = 10;
           
            cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
            cardview.setRadius(5);
            cardview.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            cardview.setMaxCardElevation(8);
            TextView textview = new TextView(this);
            textview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
            textview.setText("CardView Programmatically");
            textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textview.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
            textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            cardview.addView(textview);
            constraintLayout.addView(cardview);
            id = i;
        }
    }
```

[image: CardView to be replicated]

Comment: why not use a recyclerview instead ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Not sure how to use it but I'll check it also how can I get ids of the already displayed cardview for reference?